# deploying multiple changesets

Tags: administration, deployment

I have made several deployment changesets. They all relate to the one object, e.g., custom_object__c, i.e., changeset1 deploys field1__c, changeset2 deploys field2__c. Is it possible to validate all at the same time, or pretty much one after to other, i.e., not to have to wait for one changeset to finish validation before kicking off the next.

Comment: Why have you split your change set this way?

Comment: What type of behavoir would you expect or want, validation at the same time, where compatibility between your change sets is tested, or each individually against the existing org setup ?

Answer (score 3):

I think with changesets you will have to go with 'one after other' approach. To avoid this kind of trouble i use ant tool. once ant is setup deployment is as easy as single click.

One more option is to use Eclipse IDE for deployment.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/index_Left.htm#CSHID=forcemigrationtool_install.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fforcemigrationtool_install.htm|SkinName=webhelp

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Deploy_Force.com_Applications_Faster